# Adding attributes to dynamic Xamarin.Android controls through styles.xml

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add style attributes to dynamically created controls in Xamarin.Android, similar to how they can be applied from resources in WPF.

For an example, I have the below axml of a table row and some buttons (placed within a linearlayout)

```xml
<TableRow
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#5292C7"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="Example Couple Name Here"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Expand"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

(Which when rendered looks like this)

[image]

I'm able to create the controls and put them together with code such as this, but logically there must be a better way than just manually applying each style attribute individually in code.

```cs
// Top Row
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
topRow.AddView(tableRow);

// Couple Text
TextView coupleText = new TextView(this);

coupleText.Text = "Example Couple Name Here";
coupleText.TextSize = 15;

TableLayout.LayoutParams coupleTextLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
coupleTextLayoutParams.LeftMargin = 10;
coupleTextLayoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterVertical|GravityFlags.Left;
coupleText.LayoutParameters = coupleTextLayoutParams;
coupleText.LayoutParameters = new TableRow.LayoutParams(1);

tableRow.AddView(coupleText);
```

An example style to apply would be something like this from the styles.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="CustomTextViewStyle">
   <item name="android:text">Example Couple Name Here</item>
   <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
   <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
   <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|left</item>
   <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Which could be applied with something like this... (theoretically)

```cs
// Couple Text
TextView coupleText = new TextView(this);

coupleText.style = Resources.Style("CustomTextViewStyle");

tableRow.AddView(coupleText);
```

Is this something which exists or is the only way for this do be done dynamically though code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `SetTextAppearance` to set the style dynamically

Set the id first.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Example Couple Name Here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_weight="1"           
        style="@style/CustomTextViewStyle"/>
```

And then use the code below.

```
var textview = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        textview.SetTextAppearance(Resource.Style.CustomTextViewStyle);
```

If you create the control dynamically, you could use the code below.

```
TextView coupleText = new TextView(this);
        coupleText.SetTextAppearance(Resource.Style.CustomTextViewStyle);
```

**Updated:**

```
var tablelayout = new TableLayout(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, Resource.Style.CustomTextViewStyle));
        var tableRow = new TableRow(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, Resource.Style.CustomTextViewStyle)));
```

Comment: I understand that this is how to set it manually within the axml file, however this issue is in regards to the dynamic generation of controls with styles applied from the styles.xml file, not the standard manual implementation.

Comment: If you want to do this dynamically, you could use `SetTextAppearance` property.

Comment: @wendy-zang-msft That property only applies to a textview, how would a style be applied to a tablerow or tablelayout as they do not have 'SetTextAppearance?

Comment: For the tablelayout and tablerow, you could use the `ContextThemeWrapper` to set the style. Please check my update.